# Calculating the pH of buffer solution made of two salts of a polyprotic acid

Tags: acid-base, solutions, ph

When we are making a buffer solution by solutions of a weak acid and its salt like $\ce{CH3COOH}$ and $\ce{CH3COONa}$, or by a weak base and its salt like $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{NH4Cl}$, we can use the Henderson equation to determine its $\mathrm{pH}$. But, when we are making a buffer solution by two salts of a polyprotic acid like $\ce{Na2HPO4}$ and $\ce{NaH2PO4}$, how can we calculate the resulting $\mathrm{pH}$? Can Henderson's equation still be used? Or, is there any other formula?

For example, the pH of a solution of $\ce{NaHCO3}$ is given by the formula $\frac{1}{2}(\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1} + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2})$. But what would be the formula if the salt is from a triprotic acid? Again, what will be the formula if the solution is a mixture of salts?

I need a theoretical calculation of the $\mathrm{pH}$, and this is not for any laboratory type experiment.

Comment: You can use Henderson-Hasselbach. The equations will independently hold for both equilibria. You use use the total amount in solution to compute the actual amounts.

Comment: A useful internet search for this type of problem is 'systematic calculation of pH'. These calculations can get messy pretty quickly, so take it slow.

Comment: @Zhe How can I use the equation?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8254/calculating-approximate-ph-of-polyprotic-acids?rq=1